# How to insert zero counts uniformly with Dataset Counts query

Tags: dataset, associations

`Missing[]` is generated when an association does not contain the specified key.

```
data = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>} // Dataset
```

[image]

This situation occurs when using `Counts` where there are zero instances of a value in some records, as illustrated in this result of a query that I won't bother copying here:

[image]

This is Not to be confused with counting missing values, eg, the 263 `Missing[]` `"age"` values in Titanic data, and the "" keys above).

How to insert key-value pairs representing zero counts to obtain uniform keys in the {Association__}?.

The inserted keys should ideally appear in the same order as they are by the built-in Datset Format functionality (not contained in the Normal form) .

Desired output for `data` is:

```
{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 0|>, <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> 3, 
   "c" -> 4|>} // Dataset
```

[image]

EDIT:

It seems `KeyUnion` performs exactly this function:

```
data[KeyUnion] // Normal

(*    {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, 
      "c" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"]|>, <|"a" -> 
       Missing["KeyAbsent", "a"], "b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>} *)
```

However, it seems immune to `ReplaceAll`:

```
data[KeyUnion, All, Replace[#, Missing[__] :> 0] &] // Normal 

(* {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, 
  "c" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"]|>, <|"a" -> 
   Missing["KeyAbsent", "a"], "b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>} *)
```

EDIT 2:

Elaborating on WReach's solution using KeyUnion composed with the subquery.

Since the example data is actually structured as key-value pairs, it seems appropriate to extend this question as opposed to asking a new one, though the focus now is on KeyUnion, not the replacement for the `Missing` data.

```
raw2 = <|a -> {"Copy", "Copy", "Copy", "", "", "", "Copy"}, 
    b -> { "Paste", "", "Paste", "Paste", "", "Paste", "Paste"}, 
    c -> {"Copy", "Paste", "Copy", "Copy", "", "", "Paste"}, 
    d -> {"Paste", "", "", "Paste", "", "Paste", "Paste"}|> // 
   Dataset;
```

Even though Dimensions are the same as `raw` in his answer, and also, `raw2[All, Counts] // Normal` gives:

```
<|a -> <|"Copy" -> 4, "" -> 3|>, b -> <|"Paste" -> 5, "" -> 2|>, 
 c -> <|"Copy" -> 3, "Paste" -> 2, "" -> 2|>, 
 d -> <|"Paste" -> 4, "" -> 3|>|>
```

It's not clear to me at what level to apply `KeyUnion`, eg:

```
raw2[All, KeyUnion, Counts] // Normal

(* <|a -> Missing["Failed"], b -> Missing["Failed"], 
 c -> Missing["Failed"], d -> Missing["Failed"]|> *)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to apply an ascending function that appends each association onto a suitably defaulted prototype association, like this:

```
data[All, <| "a" -> 0, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 0, # |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

**Why didn't `KeyUnion` work?**

The question observes that the following expression does not work:

```
data[KeyUnion, All, Replace[#, Missing[__] :> 0] &]
```

One reason for this is because both `KeyUnion` and the `Replace[...]&` function are ascending operators.  Ascending operators are applied from the deepest level out.  Thus, the `Replace[...]&` is not called on the absent keys because they have not yet been added the outer `KeyUnion` ascending function, which is called afterwards.  To make this work, we would have to run successive queries:

```
data[KeyUnion][All, All, # /. _Missing -> 0 &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This has the disadvantage that it constructs an intermediate `Dataset`.  Note also that the new expression applies the replacement function to the individual association values, not to each association as a whole.  This is necessary because associations, being atomic, are opaque to `Replace` et al.  This is a second reason why the exhibited expression could not work.

The "replace" strategy can be made to work in a single query pass by explicitly specifying the key names:

```
data[All, {"a", "b", "c"}, # /. _Missing -> 0 &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

**What if the set of keys is variable?**

If we do not know the set of keys ahead of time, we can query for them using:

```
data[Union @@ # &, Keys]
(* {"a", "b", "c"} *)
```

or

```
data[Merge[First] /* Keys]
(* {"a", "b", "c"} *)
```

Of course, this will mean another pass through the dataset before the main query.

**Working from the raw data**

The question says to assume that the `Counts` query has already been run but, just for fun, here is an example of how the `Counts` could be corrected as part of that initial query:

```
raw = { {"Copy","Copy","Copy","","","","Copy"}
      , {"Paste","","Paste","Paste","","Paste","Paste"}
      , {"Copy","Paste","Copy","Copy","","","Paste"}
      , {"Paste","","","Paste","","Paste","Paste"}
      } // Dataset;

raw[KeyUnion /* Query[All, All, # /. _Missing -> 0 &], Counts]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: Out of curiosity how long have you been playing with this functionality?

Comment: @WReach, good analysis, and the KeyUnion composed with the subquery seems to be a general approach. However, `raw` should be key-value pairs. I've added EDIT2 to expand on that as it seems to break the method. Can you adapt your solution?

Comment: The difference between the `/*` behaviour between `raw2` vs `raw` is strange and possibly a bug.  In the meantime, try the supposedly equivalent expression `raw2[Values /* KeyUnion, Counts][All, All, # /. _Missing -> 0 &]`.  If you wish to pursue the `/*` difference, I suggest a new question (which I presently cannot answer).

Comment: I posted a [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56213/142) about the possible bug.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem with pattern matching has to do with the atomistic nature of an association.

```
data = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"b" -> 3, "c" -> 4|>};
Map[# /. _Missing -> 0 &, KeyUnion[data], {2}] // Dataset
```

[image]