# Possible bug involving Dataset/Query and RightComposition

Tags: bugs, dataset, query

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

**Short Version**

Why are the results of the following expressions different?

```
Dataset[{1, 2}][f /* g, z]
Dataset[<|x->1, y->2|>][Values /* f /* g, z]

(*
g[f[{z[1],z[2]}]]
g[f[z[{1,2}]]]
*)
```

**Long Version**

Consider the following dataset queries:

```
Dataset[{1, 2}][f , z]
Dataset[{1, 2}][f /* g, z]
Dataset[{1, 2}][f /* g /* h, z]

(*
f[{z[1],z[2]}]
g[f[{z[1],z[2]}]]
h[g[f[{z[1],z[2]}]]]
*)
```

The results are as expected, with the ascending operators `f`, `z`, etc. being applied from the lowest level outward.  But now consider these queries:

```
Dataset[<|x->1, y->2|>][Values /* f, z]
Dataset[<|x->1, y->2|>][Values /* f /* g, z]
Dataset[<|x->1, y->2|>][Values /* f /* g /*h, z]

(*
f[{z[1],z[2]}]
g[f[z[{1,2}]]]
h[g[z[f[{1,2}]]]]
*)
```

This time, `Values` is used to ignore the keys in the assocation.  The level 1 query operator is a composition of a descending operator with one or more ascending operators.  The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) has this to say:

> When one or more descending operators are composed with one or more
>   ascending operators (e.g. `desc /* asc`), the descending part will be
>   applied, then subsequent operators will be applied to deeper levels,
>   and lastly the ascending part will be applied to the result.

Yet note how in the second query the level two ascending operator `z` is no longer applied to the level two elements.  Worse still, in the third query the level 2 ascending operator `z` is being applied after the level 1 ascending operator `f`.

The operator reordering is most apparent in the "compiled" forms of the queries:

```
Dataset`CompileQuery[Values /* f, z]
Dataset`CompileQuery[Values /* f /* g, z]
Dataset`CompileQuery[Values /* f /* g /*h, z]

(*
Dataset`WithOverrides@*GeneralUtilities`Checked[Values/*Map[z]/*f,Identity]
Dataset`WithOverrides@*GeneralUtilities`Checked[Values/*f/*Map[z]/*g,Identity]
Dataset`WithOverrides@*GeneralUtilities`Checked[Values/*f/*g/*Map[z]/*h,Identity]
*)
```

Is this a bug, or a gap in my understanding?

**Update**

In a comment below, @TaliesinBeynon confirms that this is a bug that will be fixed in v10.0.1.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me. As if only the last ascending operator is applied if the first of the chain is descending. If this is true, you could make any op descending/ascending with something like `Select[True &] /* desc1 /*.../* descn /* Function[asc1 /* ... /* ascn@#]`

Comment: @Rojo this is indeed a bug. I've fixed it, hopefully should get into 10.0.1 (very close timing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Workaround**

Even though I cannot explain the behaviour, I note that the level one ascending operators will remain right-composed by means of a level one subquery or by a subsequent query:

```
Dataset[<|x->1, y->2|>][Values /* Query[f /* g /*h], z]
Dataset[<|x->1, y->2|>][Values, z][f /* g /*h]

(*
h[g[f[{z[1],z[2]}]]]
h[g[f[{z[1],z[2]}]]]
*)
```

Comment: Time to Accept this perhaps?