# DeleteMissing doesn't match in Association tables

Tags: dataset, associations, missing

`DeleteMissing` doesn't work in `Association` tables:

```
Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> Missing[]|>, <|"a" -> 2, 
     "b" -> 3|>}][DeleteMissing,"b"] // Normal
```

> {Missing[], 3}

Whereas `DeleteCases[_Missing]` works, as does `[All, "b"][DeleteMissing]` and `[{DeleteMissing, DeleteCases[_Missing]}, "b"]` --> `{{3},{3}}`

Comment: I think you need a level specification there to make it work: for instance, try `Dataset[...][DeleteMissing[#, 1, 2] &]`.

Comment: I originally (and somewhat tentatively) voted to close this item as a duplicate of [(59595)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59595/142).  However, @alancalvitti pointed out the additional question about operators of the form `{...}`, so I have retracted my _Close_ vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `Dataset` (and `Query`) indicates that `DeleteMissing` is a descending operator.  This means that it is applied to the original list *before* the `"b"` suboperator is applied.  Since none of the original list elements have the head `Missing`, the descending `DeleteMissing` is effectively a null operation in this case.

**Original Case - DeleteMissing**

What we need to do is convert the operator into an ascending operator.  We start with the original case:

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a"->1,"b"->Missing[]|>,<|"a"->2,"b"->3|>}];

ds[DeleteMissing, "b"] // Normal
(* {Missing[], 3} *)
```

Any descending operator can be converted into an ascending operator by wrapping it with `Query[...]`:

```
ds[Query[DeleteMissing], "b"] // Normal
(* {3} *)
```

Pure functions are also treated as ascending:

```
ds[DeleteMissing[#]&, "b"] // Normal
(* {3} *)
```

Composing a descending operator with a preceding ascending operator will also convert it -- `#&` is a terse choice:

```
ds[#& /* DeleteMissing, "b"] // Normal
(* {3} *)
```

As noted in the question, performing a second query will allow the descending operator to be applied in descending fashion, but after the operations in the first query are complete:

```
ds[All, "b"][DeleteMissing] // Normal
(* {3} *)
```

**DeleteCases**

`DeleteCases` is an ascending operator, which is why it gives the desired result:

```
ds[DeleteCases[_Missing], "b"] // Normal
(* {3} *)
```

**{DeleteMissing}**

The `{...}` operator is (usually) an ascending operator.  Thus, any suboperators it contains are applied after the other query descending operators:

```
ds[{DeleteMissing}, "b"] // Normal
(* {{3}} *)
```

While tangential to the present question, note that in some circumstances the `{...}` operator can be considered a descending operator.  This happens if and only if the contained suboperators are all simple part operators.  For example:

```
{<|"a" -> 11|>, <|"a" -> 22|>, <|"a" -> 33|> } // Query[{2, 3}, "a"]
(* {22, 33} *)
```

This exception is made because even though part operators alter the descending structure, they do so in a well-defined fashion which is akin to filtering.  The query machinery can still infer useful properties about the result of such part filtering.  `DeleteMissing` is not so benign, and can change the shape of the data in ways that are more difficult to reason about up front.  The difference is that a list of part operators generates a result of fixed cardinality, whereas `{DeleteMissing}` generates a result of varying cardinality.  So `{DeleteMissing}` does not qualify for the exception and is interpreted as an ascending operator.

Comment: Given your explanations, I don't see why does this works as intended `[{DeleteMissing, DeleteCases[_Missing]}, "b"]`. Is it b/c it's automatically wrapped in `Query`?

Comment: The `{...}` operator is (usually) an ascending operator.  I have updated the response to discuss this case, as well as `DeleteCases`.