# Applying a function to a Dataset column conditional on another slot's value

Tags: functional-style, dataset, associations, query

How to apply a function to a column conditional on another slot's value?

The Dataset [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) show only how to apply a function to named slots independently. The `{key-> foo}` operator can only access values associated to `key`

Given input dataset:

```
    data = <|"data1" -> <|"PLATFORM" -> "GoogleDrive", "LOCATION" -> "path1"|>, 
 "data2" -> <|"PLATFORM" -> "Dropbox", "LOCATION" -> "path2"|>, 
 "data3" -> <|"PLATFORM" -> "GoogleDrive", "LOCATION" -> "path3"|>|> //Dataset;
```

Want to apply  `foo` to `"LOCATION"` if `"PLATFORM"=="Dropbox"` is `True`, yielding the modified data:

[image]

This workaround solution using `GroupBy` and `Merge` is ugly,  rearranges data's rows (undesirable), and forces the user to define Identity functions:

```
platformFunctions = <| "GoogleDrive" -> Identity, "Dropbox" -> foo|> ;

{data [GroupBy[Key@"PLATFORM"]] // Normal, platformFunctions} // 
      Merge[Normal[
         Dataset[First[#]][All, {"LOCATION" -> Last[#]}]] &] // 
     Values  // Normal // Flatten // Association // Dataset
```

[image]

Is there more convenient method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
data[All, MapAt[foo, #, #PLATFORM /. {"Dropbox" -> "LOCATION", _ -> {}}] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Or, if one prefers `If`:

```
data[All, MapAt[foo, #, If[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox", "LOCATION", {}]] &]
```

**Edit**

The preceding expressions use `MapAt` with a fixed function (`foo`) and a conditional set of parts (either `"LOCATION"` or an empty list).  As @alancalvitti notes in the comments, `MapAt` can also be used with a conditional function (either `foo` or `Identity`) against a fixed part (`"LOCATION"`):

```
data[All, MapAt[If[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox", foo, Identity], #, "LOCATION"] &]
```

This is essentially the same as [@LeonidShifrin's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59800/142).

**Edit 2 - Dynamic Query**

We could also apply a dynamic query operator:

```
data[All, Query[If[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox", {"LOCATION" -> foo}, All]]@# &]
```

Comment: Thanks WReach. This variation also works: `data[All, 
 MapAt[If[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox", foo, Identity], #, "LOCATION"] &]` . As of 10.0.1 `MapAt` operator form seems broken though.

Comment: @alancalvitti I added your variation to my answer, thanks.  I haven't got 10.0.1 yet, but I am quite disappointed if it has introduced new bugs into `MapAt`.

Comment: Other bugs besides op form? Broken in 10.0.0. too.

Comment: @alancalvitti Okay, if we are talking about the known 10.0.0 bugs then I'm still disappointed but not quite as much :)

Comment: I wonder how they keep record of the increasing number of functions as various issues emerge. A giant screen w/ all Mathematica symbols layed out & color mapped... or scroll like stock exchange.

Comment: @alancalvitti how is the MapAt operator form broken?

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon I believe this is a reference to the surprising behaviour of operator forms discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56213/142), [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58463/142), and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59595/142).  I don't have 10.0.1 yet, but I hear reports that only some of these have been addressed.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps, there is a better one, but here is one that comes to mind:

```
ClearAll[transform];
transform["Dropbox"] := foo;
transform[_] := Identity;
```

and then

```
data[All, With[{tr = transform[#PLATFORM]}, MapAt[tr, #, {Key["LOCATION"]}]] &]
```

Comment: Well I didn't want to bloat the example but the actual data has many columns. Can you modify with something similar to this? (`Append[
 Complement[data[1, Keys] // Normal, {"LOCATION"}] // Normal // 
  AssociationMap[Identity],
 {"LOCATION" -> (If[#PLATFORM === "Dropbox", foo[#LOCATION], #LOCATION]&)}]`

Comment: @alancalvitti See my edit for a better approach.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, this question is already answered, but I want to add my 'preferred way' here:

First, we define a new operator:

```
ApplyIf[f_, g_, x_] := If[TrueQ[f[x]], g[x], x];
ApplyIf[f_, g_][x_] := ApplyIf[f, g, x];
```

Then we do the query:

```
data[All, ApplyIf[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox"&, MapAt[foo, "LOCATION"]]]
```

I think it's pretty clear -- we're using composition to nicely separate the condition from the action.

`ApplyIf` should probably exist in the core language. The particular compound `Map[ApplyIf[test, f]]` is extremely common, I find.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another relatively straightforward approach:

```
 data[All, <|#, "LOCATION" -> If[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox", foo[#LOCATION], #LOCATION]|> &]
```

Or using Mr.Wizard's suggestion:

```
data[All, <|#, "LOCATION" -> If[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox", foo, # &][#LOCATION]|> &]
```

Comment: Nice.  I believe it could also be written: `data[All, <|#, "LOCATION" -> If[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox", foo, # &][#LOCATION]|> &]`

Comment: @RunnyKine, the difference is that this retains the existing columns and presumably their order too.

Comment: @Simplex, that's great. That's the form I'll use - wish I'd waited to accept.

Comment: To Taliesin or others involved with Dataset dev, note despite the simplicity of Simplex's query, "LOCATION" appears 3 times. Can you implement a more compact operator?

Comment: @alancalvitti, conceptually, can one do better than having one "LOCATION" for where the result should be stored and another "LOCATION" for calculating the value? Mr.Wizard's approach works for me in that the final value with your function is "base/path2" - and it only uses "LOCATION" twice. Are you getting or expecting a different result?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Simplex is correct, I retract earlier comment.

Comment: @Simplex, Re first part of your comment: the rows are determined by the value of "PLATFORM" and the columns by "LOCATION". Each is referenced once.

Comment: @alancalvitti, after learning about MapAt from the answers of Leonid Shifrin and WReach, I see what you mean. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 2):

A not nice alternative could be

```
data[GroupBy@Key@"PLATFORM"][
   {"Dropbox" -> Query[All, { "LOCATION" -> foo}]}][
   Apply[Join]]
```

Hopefully soon we'll be able to use data on the lhs, and/or have an advanced `MapAt`.

Comment: Interesting use of Apply, but prefer WReach and my variation using MapAt. But no op form in 10.0.1, is that what you mean by advanced?

Comment: Yes. I meant I hoped something like this could eventually work `data[MapAt[foo, {Select[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox" &], "LOCATION"}]]`

Comment: But without any changes to `MapAt` I would hope this could work too`data[{Select[#PLATFORM == "Dropbox" &] -> {"LOCATION" -> foo}}]`